# Awk Loop | Multiple Lines

Tags: unix, loops, awk

I need some help, with a loop and Awk command. I need to filter, the output of ping test script where the result is:

```
--- hostname1 ping statistics ---
15 packets transmitted, 14 packets received, 6% packet loss
--- hostname2 ping statistics ---
15 packets transmitted, 15 packets received, 0% packet loss
--- hostname3 ping statistics ---
15 packets transmitted, 15 packets received, 0% packet loss
--- hostname3 ping statistics ---
15 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 86% packet loss
```

... and what I need is something like a loop and awk who filter:

Line 1 -> awk '{print $(NF-3)}' -> hostname1

Line 2 -> awk '{print $(NF-2)}' -> Here I also need the CUT of the % number, if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[ping command here] | awk '/^---/ {printf("%s ", $2)} /%/ { print $7} {next}'
```

Comment: :O well this solves me a lot of grep's and awk's, you rules! thanks a lot.